# Regex help to match until space with digit

Tags: regex

I am trying to build regex to extract certain fields but one of the field(Type) could have multiple spaces. so I am looking to match until it finds space with digit (\s\d).

My regex but its not working for 3rd sample log. Attached regex 101 screenshot

```
Added:\s+(?<Type>[^\d]+)\s(?P<Transaction_ID>\d+)\s[^\(]+\((?P<Status>\w+)
```

Sample Logs

```
[2023-08-31T12:02:40,758] [async-1 ] INFO  Added: ABC XYX CCC 265333655 IR_TEST (VERIFIED)
[2023-08-31T12:02:41,192] [async-1 ] INFO  Added: XX_Rates 265332643 IR_TEST (VERIFIED)
[2023-08-31T12:02:43,452] [async-1 ] INFO  Added: XX_Rates_4_XX 26533555 IR_TEST (VERIFIED)
```

[image]

Comment: `Added:\s+(?<Type>\S.*?)\s+(?P<Transaction_ID>\d+)[^(]*\((?P<Status>\w+)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Added:\s+(?<Type>\S.*?)\s+(?P<Transaction_ID>\d+)[^(]*\((?P<Status>\w+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RXFZyF/1).

*Details*:

- `Added:` -  a literal string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?<Type>\S.*?)` - Group "Type": a non-whitespace and then any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?P<Transaction_ID>\d+)` - Group "Transaction_ID": one or more digits
- `[^(]*` - zero or more chars other than `(`
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(?P<Status>\w+)` - Group "Status": one or more word chars.